# Why is my koa application timing out when testing a route with Jest/Supertest

Tags: async-await, jestjs, supertest, koa2, koa-router

**Summary of Problem**
Receiving `: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout` when trying to run a test with Jest and supertest.

**Specs**
Koa2 project, Jest/Supertest testing, Babel 7.9.0 recommended configuration

**What I've tried**
I have a simple test from the same file running which I omitted from the code below for brevity.  I've also tried sending an HTTP request from the browser - this file is imported & 'listen'ed in a server file.  The request is failing because it is blocked by a CORS policy - I think this is a problem for another day and isn't affecting my test timing out.

I also tried removed `.callback()` from the supertest(..) call:

`const response = await supertest(app).post('/save-material');`

- at which point I get `TypeError: app.dress is not a function.`

Here is  the content of my test file:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

const app = require('../../src/server/app.js')
const supertest = require('supertest')
 
test('save-material returns response', async() => {
    const response = await supertest(app.callback()).post('/save-material');
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body.status).toBe('success');
    expect(response.body.msg).toBe('Material saved')
});
```

Here is the content of the imported file (app.js) from above:

```js
require('@babel/register'); // not entry point - but is entry point for some tests
const Koa = require('koa');
var Router = require('koa-router')
const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router
    .post('/save-material', async(ctx) => {
        ctx.response = {
            status: 'success',
            msg: 'Material saved'
        }
        return ctx;
    })

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

module.exports = app;
```